# Boas praticas Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Vejo diversos programadores chamarem todas as views para construção de uma página no controller exemplo:

```
$this->load->view('head',$var);
$this->load->view('home');
$this->load->view('script');
$this->load->view('fim_html');
```

---

```
<html>
  <?php $this->load->view('head');?>
  <body>
    <?php echo $conteudo ;?>
  </body>
    <?php $this->load->view('script');?>
  </html>
```

Eu sei que funciona do mesmo jeito, mas isso atrapalha em algo? (além da organização do código)

Qual a melhor forma de utilizar a inserção dos códigos no Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente adicionar muitas *view* na *controller* não é muito bom, por isso acabei encontrado uma *library* bem simples que utilizo.

Para utilizar a *library* crie o arquivo **Template.php** em `application/views/Template.php` e adicione o seguinte código:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template {
    var $template_data = array();

    function set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    function load($template = '', $view = '' , $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {               
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->set('contents', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));         
        return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data, $return);
    }
}
```

Adicione no arquivo `application/config/autoload.php` a library para carregar com aplicação

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('template');
```

Crie o arquivo **template.php** (ou a nomenclatura que quiser) na pasta *view* e adicione o seguinte código como teste:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="contents"><?= $contents ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A variável **$contents** é onde a *view* que deseja será inserida.
Como exemplo, cri uma *view* com o nome **about.php** com o seguinte código:

```
<h1>About</h1>
<p>I'm so human!</p>
```

Agora para utilizar o template adicione na **controller**:

```
$this->template->load('template', 'about');
```

Onde:

- **template** : Nome do arquivo do template criado na pasta *view*;
- **about** : Nome do arquivo que contem o conteúdo que deseja inserir na variável **$contents**.

Caso queira adicionar dados que serão utilizados na *view*, só adicionar o array como terceiro parâmetro, como mostra o exemplo:

```
$this->template->load('template', 'about', array(‘titulo’=> “Titulo da pagina”));
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A tudo bem, faço sim, irei editar a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma melhor forma. Há n forma de fazer algo. Eu particularmente acho que fica ruim ficar carregando muitas Views no Controller.

Eu comecei estudar CodeIgniter vindo do background ASP.NET MVC. Lá tem o conceito de MasterPage/Layout. Eu consegui fazer algo próximo disso com o CodeIgniter.

Tenho uma página masterpage que tem a estrutura básica do HTML, ela irá carregar uma View para Menu, Rodapé, e também irá carregar uma outra View que é conteúdo em si.

**masterpage.php**

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?=$viewtitle?></title>
    <link href="<?=base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php $this->load->view("menu"); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?php
          // aqui serão carregadas as views parciais
          $this->load->view($viewname);
         ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->load->view("rodape"); ?>

    <script src="<?=base_url('/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url('/assets/js/util.js')?>"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para isso criei um Controller na pasta Core

**MY_Controller.php**

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

  // variavel que será retornada para as views
  // irá conter as informações necessárias para a view manipular as informações
  protected $data;

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // declara o array que contem as informacoes que vao para a view
    $this->data = array();
  }

  public function setData($nome, $valor) {
    $this->data[$nome] = $valor;
  }

  protected function setView($nome, $titulo) {
    $this->setData("viewname", $nome);
    $this->setData("viewtitle", $titulo);
  }

  public function loadView($nome, $titulo) {
    $this->setView($nome, $titulo);
    $this->load->view("masterpage", $this->data);
  }

}
```

Utilizo assim

```
class Produto extends BaseController {

   public function listarProdutos(){
      $this->load->model("ProdutoModel");
      $this->setData("produtos", $this->ProdutoModel->listar());

      // criei uma view chamada listagemProdutos.php
      // ela será carregada dentro da masterpage.php
      $this->loadView("listagemProdutos", "Listagem de Produtos");
   }  
}
```

**listagemProdutos.php**

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($produtos as $produto) {?>
  <li><?=$produto->nome?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```